# get icons for files and folders

Tags: google-drive-api

been searching for a day now and can't see anything. I'd like to get the icons for the files and folders in their current state.

I was hoping for something like:

`http://api.gogole.com/gdrive-sdk/icons/{$file_id}.png`

or to have a link to the icon in the items array[] returned from listing the files.

any help appreciated,
daithi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thumbnail for each file is included in the file metadata. Check the `thumbnailLink` property:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files