# Can I use the default file type icons in GoogleDrive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Not sure here is the best place to ask the question, but I searched a lot without finding the answer. 
I am creating a Web App which can get the file information from Google Drive and show it to the end user.
But I don't know if I can use the default file type icons displayed in Google Drive, or I have to create on my own.
Hope someone can help me with the question and thanks a lot in advance.

My original question seemed not clear enough. Sorry for that.
I know how to achieve the file type icons that for such as Google Doc, Google Sheets and so on. But I don't know whether I can use them in my Web App since I will show those icons to the end user as a part of my App.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get icons for files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786253/get-icons-for-files-and-folders)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But my question is if I can use the icon rather than how to get it.

Comment: You can always extract the icon from the HTML source code; the problem is whether the icons are free to use for such purpose if you're not obtaining via Google Drive SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what I wanted to ask. Understand it's not a purely technical question. But I just can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The google drive api is just a file system api.  It returns information about the files and directories on google drive.

The file type icon is probably something that has been added in the Google Drive website.   UI features are not part of the API.

You are going to have to check the file type and create your own check to determin which icon you would like to use for each type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't know if I can use those UI features created by Google for free.

Comment: the API returns a file type you decide what imagine to display.  I don't understand the issue.

Comment: OP wants to serve google's representation of the filetypes instead of their own icon set.

Comment: I realize that and am trying to point out that it is outside the spec of the API if he wants that icon set hes going to have to do it himself with the data returned that being the name of the type